# Find all shortest paths between two nodes in a graph without adding weight attributes

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path, dijkstra

Given a directed graph ***G***, source node ***s***, target node ***t*** and a weight function ***f***.
Is it possible to calculate all shortest paths between s-t using networkx without adding the weights as edge attributes?

For a single shortest path I am using [single_source_dijkstra](https://testfixsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra.html)

```
shortest_path = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, source=s, target=t, weight=f)
```

I know that if I would add the weights as edge attributes, I could use [all_shortest_paths](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths)

```
all_shortest_paths = nx.all_shortest_paths(G, source=s, target=t, weight='weight', method='dijkstra')
```

Is there a similar way of computing all shortest paths, where I don't have to add weight attributes to every edge and instead input a weight function f and get a list of (path_length, path)-tuples?

Comment: Could you clarify: Are you interested in the path length or some metric generated by edge attributes that are traversed?

Comment: To find the shortest path of an un-weighted graph you can use [Breadth-First Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Breadth+First+Search&oq=Breadth+First+Search&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @math_noob Let me give you a minimal example to answer your question:
Let G = (V, A) be a directed graph with, V = {1, 2, 3, 4}, E = {(1,2), (1,4), (2,3), (4,3), (1,3)}.
The edges have the attribute 'w'={(1,2): 1, (1,4): 2, (2,3): 2, (4,3): 1, (1,3): 100}. I now want to calculate all shortest s-t path with s=1, t=3. My cost function for an edge (n1,n2) is defined as:
`def f(n1,n2,d):
if n1 in [2, 4]:
return d['w'] + 1
else:
return d['w']`

Here d=G[n1][n2].

So the 2 shortest paths are [1,2,3] and [1,4,3] both with length 4.
I want to return them as [(4, [1,2,3]), (4, [1,4,3]).

Comment: @c0der My edges have weights, which are based on the edge attributes, I just don't want to calculate them for all edges, since my graph is really big. But you are right, maybe BFS could be a valid approach here. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to pre calculate the weights of the entire graph. You only need to calculate the weights of the next edges to be processed. The edges to the neighbors. (BSF can not handle different weights)

Comment: @c0der You are completely right. This seems to be the most efficient way of solving my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two easy to implement possibilities.
A: Define a function, that returns the sepcific weights you to an edge, add as attribute to graph, then run the all_shortest_paths on the edge attributed you just created.

B: Simply iterate over all nodes in the graph:

```
results = []
for n1 in G.nodes():
    for n2 in G.nodes():
        shortest_path = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, source=n1, target=n2, weight=f)
        results.append(shortest_path)
```

EDIT:

You can use

```
nx.all_shortest_paths = nx.all_shortest_paths(G, source=s, target=t, weight=cost_function, method='dijkstra')
```

with a custom function.
It will correctly return all shortest paths based on your metric.
But be aware, as far as I understand the implementation in networkx, this will calculate the shortest paths for all nodes, then simply return as selection based on your source and target node.

It will not return you the path lenghts, as they are all the same...
You can get it out if you would have to...

Comment: To A:
I do not want to add all weights as attributes since my graph is pretty big and I need a fast runtime.

To B:
I do not want to solve the all pairs shortest path problem, but find all paths between a defined source s and target t, which have the same minimum length.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of large are we talking about? 1000, 10000, 100000?

Comment: I have to find the shortest path between s-t in a graph with > 500.000 edges for >10.000 s-t pairs in every iteration that I do. For every s-t pair I have different edgeweights. I have to perform between 2-6 iterations.
The BFS approach suggested before seems to be the most efficient way of solving this problem.